# ELI5: (Reactive cocoa ) - React to a Filter returning no

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am very new to reactive cocoa and I'm still getting my head around it.

But I feel like this should be possible:

1. Create a signal around a search for a file.  (imageSearchSignal)
2. If the the image isn't found use the download signal and download it. (downloadImageSignal)

So what I'm doing is the following, but what I want to do is add the downloadImageSignal if the image search fails. (basically respond to the filter saying no)

```
    [[[imageSearch filter:^BOOL(NSString *path) {

        if (path.length > 0) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }] map:^id(NSString *path) {

        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    }] subscribeNext:^(UIImage *image) {

        // because I want to filter it this would never really happen.  I send no if length is 0.  
        if (!image) { // feel like this should be done in the pipeline somewhere. 
            [[self signalForImageDownload:stepId] subscribeNext:^(UIImage *downloadedImage) {
                [subscriber sendNext:downloadedImage];
                [subscriber sendCompleted];
            }];
        }
        else {
            [subscriber sendNext:image];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }

    } error:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);

    }];
```

Example of the flow I'm looking for:
[image: Example of the flow I'm looking for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that whole block is wrapped in a `createSignal:`, hence the calls to subscriber. But that's probably not necessary. Instead of:

```
RACSignal *imageSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber>subscriber) {
    [[[imageSearch filter:^BOOL(NSString *path) {
    ...
```

Just assign it to be a derived signal:

```
RACSignal *imageSignal = [[[imageSearch filter:^BOOL(NSString *path) {
    return path.length > 0;
}] map:^id(NSString *path) {
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}] flattenMap:^(UIImage *image) {
    if (image) {
        return [RACSignal return:image];
    } else {
        return [self signalForImageDownload:stepId];
    }
}];
```

`flattenMap` is like mapping into a signal of signals and then flattening the result. Since in one of the cases you don't need to do any work, you can use `return:` to create a dummy signal of just one value.

However, depending on the behavior of `imageSearch`, this might not be quite what you want. This will give you one image for each `imageSearch` (or more, if `signalForImageDownload` sends more than one next!), but there's a way to throw out old values as soon as `imageSearch` sends another value: change `flattenMap` to `map` followed by `switchToLatest`.

Comment: Thank you,  `[RACSignal return:image]` was my missing ingredient.